# Steam API Get SteamID using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, steam

Been running into what appears to be the Same Origin Policy which is causing quite some headache!

To cut to the chase, I am essentially trying to acquire a user's steam64id when only supplied their username.

For example, my username: "Emperor_Jordan" I would go to:

http://steamcommunity.com/id/emperor_jordan?xml=1

And the steamid I need is right at the top.  So I figured I would use JQuery Ajax to acquire this and parse out the id I need for later usage (steamapi usage requires the steam64id) as follows.  Here is a snippet of the code in question:

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://steamcommunity.com/id/emperor_jordan/?xml=1",
datatype: "xml",
complete: function()
{
    alert(this.url)
},
success: parse
});

function parse(xml)
{
    alert("parsing");
    _steamID = $(xml).find("steamID64").text();
}
```

The problem here is while I do get the alert for the completion, I never see "parsing".  Ever.  It never gets that callback, which leads me to believe I am running into the SOP (same origin policy).

Am I approaching this the wrong way, is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct. [You *are* running into the same-origin policy:](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/M84kc/)

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://steamcommunity.com/id/emperor_jordan/?xml=1. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

and [it looks like Steam does not offer a cross-origin solution like JSONP](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API). That means you're back to the old-but-reliable solution: fetch the data on your server, not in the browser.

---

Some relevant feedback on the Steam Web API: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/Feedback#API_Considerations_for_Web_Developers

Comment: I feared as much, not a real issue though.  Server side I go.  Thanks!  (Also thanks for the blazing fast answer!)

Comment: There are also service that solve this problem, so you don't have to setup a server-script for this like http://json2jsonp.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a proxy server in Heroku in order to get the data. Cors is restricting us to call the data directly to our browser not server to server interaction. So we need a proxy server to send the requests and receive the data on our behalf. It's working for me.

Thanks in advance.