# Struggling with JSON / JSONP

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm really new to the world of JSON goodness, and am really struggling to get a cross-domain request to work. Really doing my head in :(

The code I have is:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.steampowered.com/IEconDOTA2_570/GetHeroes/v0001/?language=en_us&key=<MY KEY HERE>&callback=?', function(data) {
    alert("success");
});
```

From what I can understand, adding the &callback=? to the end of the url means it will call the function I have next, which should pop up a simple alert box. For some reason this never happens though. When looking in Firebug, I can see the Response fine and the expected data results are in there....yet my function is never called. If however, I try to define a specific function for the callback, I do not get a response.  Really confused and would GREATLY appreciate any help.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Try with &jsoncallback=? instead of &callback=?

Comment: JSONP has to be supported by the server, and the Steam API does not support it. Also See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13150928/67824.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$.ajax({ url:'http://api.steampowered.com/IEconDOTA2_570/GetHeroes/v0001/?language=en_us&key=<MY KEY HERE>',
         dataType:'jsonp',
         succes:function(data) {
           alert("success");
        }
});
```

`$.getJSON` - it is for json only. But `$.ajax` with `dataType:'jsonp',` will add callback correctly

Comment: Trying this provided the same results as my code. Could it be an issue with the URL I am making the call to? Do not all websites allow for jsonp? If so, does this mean I am stuck? Thanks!

Comment: @user1865880  Open developer tools (F12 in all borwsers, may need to instal Firebug on FF) and see network tab. Once you do that call - it should appear there. See what is returned there. Also - check your browser console. Possibly there will be some error.

Comment: Oh thank you, might be onto something. I am terribly sorry but I may still need help. in the Console I've got the following error:
SyntaxError: invalid label
"result": { 

but this is just the first line of the response....:S:S:S
"result": {
  "heroes": [
   {
    "name": "npc_dota_hero_antimage",
    "id": 1,
    "localized_name": "Anti-Mage"
   },
and the list goes on.....

Comment: Try to change `dataType:'jsonp'`, to `dataType:'json',` I do not see anything about jsonp there. Possibly they have opened their server for coross domain requests and do not use JSONP

Comment: dataType: json results in no response from the server :S:S:S
I REALLY appreciate the help you are giving me here btw...thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method instead like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "'http://api.steampowered.com/IEconDOTA2_570/GetHeroes/v0001/?language=en_us&key=<MY KEY HERE>",
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function( data ){
    alert("success");
  }
});
```

Comment: Trying this provided the same results as my code. Could it be an issue with the URL I am making the call to? Do not all websites allow for jsonp? If so, does this mean I am stuck? Thanks!

Comment: @user1865880 According to [this](http://steamcommunity.com/dev), that website does *not* have JSONP support. So you wont be able to load the data on the client's browser.